# How to increase size of root partition at /dev/sda1 from /dev/sdb1?

Tags: boot, partitioning, root, fdisk, parted

I have an **Ubuntu 16.04 system without GUI (only command line)** with a very limited root partition (20GB) and 1 storage partition (1000GB) as below

```
sudo parted -l

Model: QEMU QEMU HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 21.5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  21.5GB  21.5GB  primary  ext4         boot


Model: QEMU QEMU HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1074GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1074GB  1074GB  primary  ext4
```

The current status of these disk are:

```
df -hP
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             27G     0   27G   0% /dev
tmpfs           5.4G  530M  4.9G  10% /run
/dev/sda1        20G   19G  194M  99% /    (almost full!!!!!)
tmpfs            27G  112K   27G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            27G     0   27G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1       985G  602G  333G  65% /rasv1 (more space!!!!!)
tmpfs           5.4G   20K  5.4G   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs           5.4G     0  5.4G   0% /run/user/1001
```

How can I increase the size of root partition for /dev/sda1 (e.g: 20GB -> 100 GB) from /dev/sdb2 (1000GB -> 900GB) online **(no liveCD, USB boot, reboot)**?

Comment: Unless you are using LVM, or zfs (or a few others) I don't think you could borrow for /sdb to feed /sda.  But this is a VM - why not make the virtual disk /sda bigger, and expand the file system for it?  And make a live USB while you are at this.

Comment: @CharlesGreen thanks, but I only have access to this VM, so seem like no other choice for me.

Comment: OK - summarizing, you have no physical access, the VM administrator will not increase your /sda (this would have to be offline anyhow) and you are space limited.  I'm going to vote for re-open, and ask a few questions - please append the results into your original question!

Comment: 1st.  Please execute `sudo du -ah -x -d 1 / | sort -rh | head -20` and also `ls -l /boot`

Comment: @CharlesGreen Thanks for your quick actions, I opened a ticket for the admin (if he says nothing I will run your command as this VM I just get controlled recently).

Comment: 20 GB should be enough under most circumstances - the commands I wrote are useful in finding out where all the space is being used up.